# How to count the number of pixels in a file in R?

Tags: r

whenever the values in `cus` range between 0-1, calculate the corresponding average in `cor` and return the result, do the same thing with 2-3,3-4,5-6,7-8.no data values are assigned as NA.

1- to read `corr`:

```
conne <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
corr <- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4, n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
#please assume a matrix of 720*1440 dimnsions
```

2- to read `cus` :

```
conne1 <- file("C:\\use.bin","rb")
cus <- readBin(conne1, numeric(), size=4, n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
#please assume a matrix of 720*1440 dimnsions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `data.table`. I am assuming that the values in `cus` are actually 1:7 (so basically not sure why you need `cusBreak`). We create a variable to count the number of pixels used to find the `mean` of each group (and don't forget to include `na.rm` if you have NAs in your data):

```
require( data.table )
DT <- data.table( "Cus" = as.vector(cus) , "Corr" = as.vector(corr) )
DT[ , Pix:=( ifelse( is.na( DT$Corr ) , 0 , 1 ) ) ]
DT[ , list( "Mean" = mean(Corr,na.rm=TRUE) , "Sum" = sum(Pix) ) , by = Cus ]
```

#### A reproducible example with toy data

```
#  Data
set.seed(12345)
corr <- matrix( rnorm(16) , 4 )
cus <- matrix( sample(0:7,16,repl=T) , 4 )
cus
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    6    6    2
#[2,]    5    7    3    2
#[3,]    2    4    7    0
#[4,]    2    1    6    0

#  Create data.table
DT <- data.table( "Cus" = as.vector(cus) , "Corr" = as.vector(corr) )

#  Order by Cus
setkey(DT,Cus)

# Variable to count pixels
DT[ , Pix:=( ifelse( is.na( DT$Corr ) , 0 , 1 ) ) ]

# Get meean of corr grouped by cus
DT[ ,  list( "Mean" = mean(Corr , na.rm = TRUE ) , "Sum" = sum(Pix) )  , by = Cus ]
#   Cus        Mean Pixels
#1:   1  0.15467236      2
#2:   5  0.70946602      1
#3:   2  0.08201096      4
#4:   6  0.71301325      3
#5:   7 -0.96710189      2
#6:   4  0.63009855      1
#7:   3 -0.91932200      1
#8:   0  0.03318392      2
```

Comment: @ZadSim if the `corr` file contains an `NA` put `0`, otherwise put `1`. Then when we come to do the `sum` to know how many pixels were counted in the `mean` NA cells don't count towards the sum because they are 0. Do you see?

Comment: @ZadSim then just use `as.integer( cusBreak )` instead of `cus` when you make the `data.table`, i.e. `DT <- data.table( "Cus" = as.integer(cusBreak) , "Corr" = as.vector(corr) )`

Comment: @ZadSim no, leave corr as it is because you want the mean of those values. cusBREAK is just a categorical classification variable used to subset corr.